# Relative Layout background not filling all the space

Tags: android, background, padding, android-relativelayout

i have a relative layout with a background image, but i want the image to fill all the layout space, i think it's a padding problem, i set to -1dip,that doesn't work.
Also before setting my padding to -1dip, when i inspect the padding with hierachy viewer.
here's my xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridView"
        android:background="@drawable/tool_bar"
        android:gravity="center"
       >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/locate" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:src="@drawable/orbit" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@drawable/snap" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />
    </RelativeLayout>
thanks
```

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into the same problem. I think by default RelativeLayout will not expand the background to its dimensions.

Ended up using a view inside in the following way:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="300px"
android:layout_height="204px">
    <View 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"       
    android:background="@android:color/white"/> //Or whatever background you pick
</RelativeLayout>
```

Not the solution I was hoping for but a solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to fill all the space by width and height use the FILL_PARENT or if you want fill the one them like fill width and not height then set the height as wrap_content or if you want to fill the height and not width then set the wrap_content to width

like here it will fill the both

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridView"
        android:background="@drawable/tool_bar"
        android:gravity="center"
       >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i want the background image to fill the relative layout space. not the relative layout to fill the whole screen

Answer (score 0):

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/tool_bar"
   >
```

Should do the trick I assume

Answer (score -1):

I think you want image filling on to Relative Layout.
You try it. It may be help you.
**fill_parent**

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/any_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_you" />
```